# How to insert string into another string with same multiple occurrences

Tags: python

How the following syntax can be simplified?

```
three='Three'
result='One-Two-%s, One-Two-%s, One-Two-%s'%(three,three,three))
```

## Edited later:

Another surprise: getting `KeyError: 'border'` on this:

```
color='#262626'
style="QProgressBar{background-color: {ph:s}}".format(ph=color)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> three = 'Three'
>>> result = 'One-Two-{ph:s}, One-Two-{ph:s}, One-Two-{ph:s}'.format(ph=three)
>>> print result
One-Two-Three, One-Two-Three, One-Two-Three
```

**Edit**:

```
>>> style="QProgressBar{{background-color: {ph:s}}}".format(ph=color)
>>> print style
QProgressBar{background-color: #262626}
```

Comment: Passing a variable should work too, right?
`result = 'One-Two-{ph:s}, One-Two-{ph:s}, One-Two-{ph:s}'.format(ph=three)`  where `three="Three"`

Comment: That's because the formatter gets confused on which `{}` is part of a format string and which `{}` is literal. For literal ones, you need to double it, i.e. `{{}}`

Answer (score 2):

Try [new-style formatting](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#format-string-syntax).

You can use a dictionary expansion to do multiple variables as well.

```
three='Three'
result='One-Two-{x:}, One-Two-{x:}, One-Two-{x:}'.format(**{'x': three})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [string formatting.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string-formatting) In your example, you would do this:

```
three = "Three"
result = "One-Two-{0}, One-Two-{0}, One-Two-{0}".format(three)
```

For the other question, change it to this:

```
style="QProgressBar{{background-color: {0}}}".format(color)
```

Comment: I answered your other question.